# Forma de obtener valor de una etiqueta p mediante javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy tratando de ver el valor con que se muestra en el navegador la etiqueta. Para propósitos de la explicación mencionare "texto" envés de "valor". inicialmente tiene el texto "prueba" luego mediante una función le cambio el texto a "auxiliar" (cadena que se encuentra en un objeto de un archivo .json), posterior en la función añado un evento

```
document.getElementById('ttlSECT1_1').addEventListener("click",ver);
```

y en un función distinta creo una la siguiente función:

```
 function ver(e) {
  if(!e) e = window.event;
  var a = e.target.id;
  var b = a.textContent;
  console.log(a);
}
```

y esto es lo de la etiqueta en el html:

```
<p id="ttlSECT1_1">título</p>
```

No me funciona la parte de la variable b en la función ver, especificamente el `.textContent` también he intentado con `.innerText`, `.innerHTML` y `.value` pero solo veo en consola el undefined.
**¿Cómo puedo ver en consola el texto?** esto lo hago porque en esa función quiero guardar ese dato en  el `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo usando `.textContent` pero en `e.target` asi:

```js
document.getElementById('ttlSECT1_1').addEventListener("click",ver);


 function ver(e) {
  if(!e) e = window.event;
  var a = e.target.id;
  var b = e.target.textContent;
  console.log(b);
}
```

```html
<p id="ttlSECT1_1">título</p>
```